# How to select ten values, five larger and five smaller than a given value in one Postgre query?

Tags: sql, hibernate, postgresql

I have an interesting question to ask you :)
Assumptions:
I am using Spring and Hibernate over Postgres database.

I have User table and every user has it's name and it's score.
I want to generate a sort of a rank where: Given the user's name I extrapolate 5 users that have more scores than the given user and 5 users that have less scores like this:

- user1  p.105
- user2  p.104
- user3  p.103
- user4  p.102
- given user  p.100
- user6  p.99
- user7  p.98
- ...

My question is: is it possible to make it in one query only? Will it be more optimal and faster in one query? Do you have any proposal of such a query?
Doing it in two queries is very simple but I want to know if there is a way to do it in one time?

Comment: Use your 2 queries with `UNION`

Comment: As far as I know hibernate dosent support union query.  [link](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-1050)

Answer (score 2):

PostgreSQL can do that with a single query. You might need to use native (raw) SQL in Hibernate. Here's one way.

```
with lowers as (
  select * 
  from test
  where score < (select score from test where user_id = 13)
  limit 5
), highers as (
  select * 
  from test
  where score > (select score from test where user_id = 13)
  limit 5
)
select * from lowers
union all
select * from highers 
union all 
select * from test where user_id = 13
order by score;
```

You should think about what should happen if there *aren't* five scores greater or five scores less than the target (user_id = 13). Also, this query won't bring in any rows that have scores identical to the target, which might or might not be what you're looking for. It also makes no attempt to get the 10 rows that are *closest* to the target.

On my dev box, which is no speedster, this query runs in 0.1 ms on a table of a million rows.

Comment: Hi Mike thank you very much for your hint, I didn't knew the "with" close so I have to study it. I also have to consider all the issues that you mentioned so we will see. I will let you know if I end up with something reasonable  :)